# Can I remove subfloor and install hardwood flooring directly on 2x6 planks?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I have 2x6 planks under 3/4 subflooring, running at a 45 degree angle. I plan on removing the 3/4 subfloor and installing hardwood flooring directly on the 2x6 planks. Is this a good idea?

Comment: What is the spacing of the joists underneath?

Comment: Pay attention to the air infiltration comments below... depending on where you live and what the space underneath is like, you might get wide humidity swings that can cause failure. If you get around to answering the joist spacing question, please also explain why you want to remove the 3/4 subfloor. (It's generally a useful ingredient in the whole system.)

Answer (score 0):

It is tough to saw without seeing a picture.  You would need to make sure the surface is level across the planks to ensure a uniform surface for the floor to sit on.  Another problem could be the transition height from room to room.

Answer (score 0):

With the 2x6 base you have a great starting point. Removing the 3/4" should not be a problem when installing new hard wood flooring. With that said I am saying this because you said planks not joist and sub floor. Planks are flat joist are the supports below. If a newer home with joist as the only support there can be several problems including air leakage but if only 3/4" decking and 2x6 it would be on 16" or less centers and T&G hard would could be installed but it would need a seal or bead of calking on each board but it can be done.